# How can i load static html through a component in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a list of static htmls and want to render it through a component in angular 4 on a click on a text href.

Comment: I gave a downvote because you did not include any code, or appear to make an attempt.

Comment: perfectly good question

Answer (score -1):

Your component should look like this:

```
<your-component [yourInput]="yourHTML"> </your-component>
```

And your component's html will look something like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourInput"></div>
```

Documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation).

If you have a list of html's then you should use *ngFor loop to show them all.

Comment: i used angular-cli.json and added those htmls to it then rendered it using a href and it worked.

Comment: "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
       "info.html",
        "assets/howToHtml/0001_htg_introduction.html",
        "assets/howToHtml/0002_htg_list.html"
      ],

Comment: <a type="text/html" href="assets/howToHtml/0001_htg_introduction.html">0001_htg_introduction</a>